# MDX - difference between AGGREGATE() and SUM() functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

I want to know what's happening below. Why are the below `MDX` queries giving varying outputs?

Note: [Measures].[Claim As Of - Count] is a calculated measure(we are using Tabular model approach). [Accident Date] is part of the DAX calculation behind this measure. This measure is related to another measure(in the calculation) which uses the [Accident Date] dimension.

**query 1**

--Error message: Infinite recursion detected. The loop of dependencies is: sumallsales -> sumallsales.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Accident Date].[MOnth].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      [Accident Date].[MOnth].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales
   ,[Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales
  } ON 0
 ,[Client].[Client Name].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [AW Cube];
```

**query 2**

---all null values

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Accident Date].[MOnth].[all]
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      [Accident Date].[MOnth].[all]
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales
   ,[Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales
  } ON 0
 ,[Client].[Client Name].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [AW Cube];
```

**query 3**

---equal and correct

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Accident Date].[Year].[all]
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      [Accident Date].[Year].[all]
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales
   ,[Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales
  } ON 0
 ,[Client].[Client Name].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [AW Cube];
```

**query 4**

---all null values

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Accident Date].[Year].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      [Accident Date].[Year].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales
   ,[Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales
  } ON 0
 ,[Client].[Client Name].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [AW Cube];
```

**query 5**

---the values using sum function are double than that using aggregate

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Accident Date].[Year].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      [Accident Date].[Year].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Accident Date].[Year].sumallsales
   ,[Accident Date].[Year].aggregateallsales
  } ON 0
 ,[Client].[Client Name].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [AW Cube];
```

Comment: Is `[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]` a standard physical measure, or is it a calculated measure? What is its definition? Is it possibly overwritten somewhere in the calculation script (or in a session calculation definition)? How is the relationship between the measure group containing this measure and the `[Accident Date]` and `[Client]` dimensions defined?

Comment: It is a calculated measure(we are using Tabular model approach). [Accident Date] is part of the DAX calculation behind this measure. This measure is related to another measure(in the calculation) which uses the [Accident Date] dimension. Do you want me to paste all those queries here? Or could you please tell me how can such scenario occur given the relationship? Thanks

Comment: Actually, I do not have much experience with MDX against a tabular model. Nevertheless, I would suggest that you edit your question entering the content of your comment, so that others coming across the query know this and do not assume - as I did - that you use a multidimensional model if you access it via MDX.